# to fill data into table in web user control from web service

Tags: java, web-services

i need to fill data into table in web user control from web service
[WebMethod]

```
public string UserInfo(string name, string email, string dob, string country,string gender,string meal)
{


}
```

Comment: So, what is your problem then?

Comment: i want pass some data from web service to table in web user control.. i don't know how to do it... so can you please help me out

Comment: But StackOverflow is for solving specific problems with _your_ code. It's not that you just come without any prior effort and ask others to do your job. If you have no idea where to start, learn how to connect to the DB from C#, then how to make inserts, then tie that up in your webmethod.

Comment: i'm getting data from user interface and sending that data to web service using jquery ajax...and now i'm not able to push it to user control ..thats my problem

Comment: Then I suggest that you reformulate the question, state the specific problem that you have, and share the exact fragments of code that are not working as they should, explaining what you think they _should_ do. Then somebody might help you. Because what you have right now looks like asking others to do your homework.

Comment: okay, just tell me how to link user control and web service